# read and write properties / @Input()@Output at same time

Tags: angular

I have a component with a counter propert

```
export class MyComponent 
{
  @Input()@Output() counter: string;
}
```

I can set the property via:

```
<mycomponent [(counter)]="parentcounter" ></mycomponent>
```

But changes made in MyComponent are not visible in the parentcomponent => parentcounter.

How can I achieve read *and* write properties in angular2+?

Comment: Your options are listed here: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular does not manage input/output like AngularJS, ouput should be bind to action (function or expression), not property. There is no way to code the equivalent of [(ngModel)] directive. Here is the simplest solution with an expression using $event:

```
export class MyComponent 
{
    @Input() counter: string;
    @Output() counterChange = new EventEmitter<String>(); 

    someEvent(newCounterValue) {
       counterChange.emit(newCounterValue);
    }
}

<mycomponent [counter]="parentcounter" (counterChange)="parentCounter = $event" ></mycomponent>
```

Note that `someEvent(newCounter)` should be called from the code which change the counter value.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about previous versions, but with Angular 9 what @claboran mentions is possible like this:

```js
export class MyComponent 
{
    @Input() counter: string;
    @Output() counterChange = new EventEmitter<string>(); 

    // whenever counter's value changes
    onCounterChange(value) {
       counterChange.emit(value);
    }
}
```

It would be set like this:

```html
<my-component [(counter)]="parentcounter" ></my-component>
```

Comment: I've never seen something like this. Wonder how does it work?

Answer (score 0):

You could implemenent some kind of custom 2-way databindinng. see: [Two way Databinding in Angular 2](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html). There is no support in AngularX in contrast to AngularJS. For instance the ngModel "[(Banana in the box)]" Two Way Binding is implemented in the ngModel Directive.